# Не работает звук в setInterval

Tags: javascript

Почему звук при клике работает, а при цикле в setInterval не работает?
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀        **Что нужно прописать, чтобы звук работал в setInterval?**

Надо, чтобы звук сам воспроизводился.

```js
function play() { 
let audio = new Audio('https://sound-pack.net/download/Sound_16486.mp3');
audio.play();  // первый метод с кнопкой работает на ура
}

let go = setInterval(function(){ 
let audio2 = new Audio('https://sound-pack.net/download/Sound_16486.mp3');
audio.play(); // второй метод цикла не работает
},1200)
```

```html
<button onclick="play()">Играй курчявый</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, это интересный прикол из серии защиты пользователей от навязчивой рекламы. Браузер не позволяет проигрывать звуки/видио(со звуком) без взаимодействия с пользователем.

То-есть все фоновые попытки проиграть звук блокируются на 100%.

Comment: ну и как это обойти?

Comment: Никак. От слова совсем... Я недели 2 боролся с этой проблемой и единственное что пришло в голову это проигрывать звук на Движение Мышкой....

Пользователь двигает мышкой, мы собираем в массив замороженные MouseMoveEvent которые ждут сигнала от background. И когда надо завершают Event проигрыванием звука. **Но это СТРАШНЫЙ КОСТЫЛЬ**

Comment: Даже видео без атрибута `muted` нельзя проиграть без user interraction.

Comment: а если в видео прописать muted, то оно будет воспроизводиться без звука?
если так, то как тогда всякие 30секундные рекламы на Ютубе сами воспроизводятся со звуком

Comment: Да! `<video muted autoplay><source ...></video>` будет работать.

Comment: Рекламы, уже происходят после user interraction... А именно MouseClickEvent ... Event от пользователя может запускать звуки, потом ты его можешь заморозить и делать в его теле всё что хочется. Вне event'а нечего такого делать нельзя.

Comment: это значит, что звук не может автоматически играть в setInterval?
и бороться с этим бессмысленно?

Comment: Ну вот тебе пример как работает звук в замороженном user event https://codepen.io/latdev/pen/WNZeKeP   В данном примере заморозкой работает asyncSleepHack, await может ожидаться долгое время... Пока не получит от другова event сообщение что надо проиграть звук... Но вызов play() должен вызывать именно user event.

Comment: Делаешь кнопку, например `включить звук`, замораживаешь MouseClickEvent в и ожидаешь сигнала от background если пришел сигнал, то проигрываешь звук. Напрямую в setInterval *никак не получиться* потому что у event нету флага что это user interraction.

Comment: На Ютуб проигрывается Трейлер канала безо всякого интерактива, но это потому, что Ютуб входит в список сайтов, которым это разрешено, в список безопасных сайтов.

Comment: Долбанные корпорации, не думал, что скажу эту фразу из Киберпанка =(
А как сделать, чтобы клик по кнопке происходил автоматически при входе на страницу без участия пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя на 8 строке вместо `audio2.play()` указано просто `audio.play()`

```js
function play() { 
let audio = new Audio('https://sound-pack.net/download/Sound_16486.mp3');
audio.play();  // первый метод с кнопкой работает на ура
}

let go = setInterval(function(){ 
let audio2 = new Audio('https://sound-pack.net/download/Sound_16486.mp3');
audio2.play(); // второй метод цикла не работает
},1200)
```

```html
<button onclick="play()">Играй курчявый</button>
```

Но можно упростить код так:

```js
function play() { 
let audio = new Audio('https://sound-pack.net/download/Sound_16486.mp3');
audio.play();  // первый метод с кнопкой работает на ура
}

let go = setInterval(function(){ 
    play()    
},1200)
```

Comment: Исправил audio.play() на audio2.play(), но все равно не работает в цикле =(